# migration Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

how to solve this error. I'm using GoDaddy server
In Abstract.php line 144:

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'glamaa_mg4'@'localhost' (using password
  : YES)

In Abstract.php line 128:

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'glamaa_mg4'@'localhost' (using password
  : YES)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are both websites on the same physical server? If not you'll have to do the MySQL connection via domain/IP address rather than localhost.

Answer (score 0):

local.xml has this username : glamaa_mg4 
Than the app/etc/env.php has username:i5762028_mg3

Would you try to make them same at both files? or the user that is valid on server

Comment: two different databases, why he needs the same user?

Comment: thanks for helping.
I copied database Magento 1 to host Magento 2 it working